# POSTGRESQL VACUUM ANALYZE fails for table with a hstore column

Tags: postgresql-8.4, hstore, vacuum

When running VACUUM ANALYZE on a table with a hstore column i get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not identify a comparison function for type hstore
```

Can I force it to complete without a comparison function and if not, how do I define one?

Comment: Full version please - `SELECT version()`. Odd issue; it works fine on my 9.2 instance.

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit

Comment: OK, so you're on quite an old point-release of 8.4 that's missing years of bug fixes. I'd check the release notes for hstore-related fixes, see if this might be a bug/limitation that was fixed since your older version. Failing that, test to see whether the same DB has the problem when loaded into a newer version. If it does, you know it's something to do with the DB.